# In MacOS, is there any way to have native Mac layout for ‘option-something’ special symbols in quoted-insert?

Tags: keyboard-layout

With `quoted-insert` (`C-q`) I can enter ‘Option-something’ extended characters, but [Emacs apparently understands them as ISO 8859-1](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/QuotedInsert). Meanwhile, MacOS has its own layout for these characters (changed with the input language or custom layouts), and there's a cheatsheet in the form of ‘Keyboard viewer.’

Is there any way to make Emacs use the same layout for `M-something` in `quoted-insert` as native applications do?

I could conceivably edit a keymap by hand to reflect the system one, but 1) I don't see a mention of a special keymap for `quoted-insert`, and 2) I'd prefer not to.

[Apparently Emacs does receive native characters if `Option` keys aren't set up as `Meta`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19081590/emacs-in-mac-does-not-understand-m-w-but-i-get-%E2%88%91-instead), however I don't have an abundance of modifier keys on my keyboard so I'd prefer to keep `Option` as `Meta` and use `quoted-insert` when needed.

Comment: While formulating the question I found out that unmapping `Meta` from `Option` apparently lets one use native special characters, and realized that I could probably make a wrapper that does the unmapping and then launches `quoted-insert`. Will try that and post results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I learned that Emacs enters native special symbols if Option isn't mapped to Meta, I went ahead and made a wrapper for `quoted-insert` that does the unmapping:

```el
(defun my/quoted-insert-wrapper (arg)
  "For quoted-insert, unmap Option from Meta so special symbols can be entered with the native Mac layout"
  (interactive "*p")
  (let ((mac-option-modifier 'none))
    (quoted-insert arg)))

;;; this should work for non-Evil setups, but haven't tested it
;; (global-set-key (kbd "C-v") #'my/quoted-insert-wrapper)

(define-key evil-insert-state-map (kbd "C-v") #'my/quoted-insert-wrapper)
```

Works like a charm so far, even for diacritic modifiers. Users of non-Latin layouts will probably also want to add a mapping for keys in their language on the same location as Latin `C-v`.

However, I'm not sure whether hijacking the option with `let` would work if lexical binding is enabled—but that's a different issue. Presumably I still could `setq` the option and then revert it after `quoted-insert`.

Comment: Some additional backgound:  The variable `mac-option-modifier` is an *alias* for `ns-alternate-modifier`, which is defined in `nsterm.m`.  The user also free to set the left/right Option keys differently; e.g., `(setq ns-alternate-modifier 'meta ns-right-alternate-modifier 'none)` will permit the right option key to behave with system defaults, and the left will be have as Meta.

Comment: @lawlist True, however afaik there's little point in keeping around methods to enter symbols in both Mac layout and ISO 8859-1. Meanwhile, touch typing advises to press the key with one hand and the modifier with the other; furthermore Option-Shift-key becomes rather cumbersome if you have to stick to one of the two Options.